# Can't install Skype in Cinnamon 19.3 , 32bit

Tags: skype, 32-bit, cinnamon

I am very new at this.
A friend gave me an hp mini Compaq notebook from 2001.
I put Linux Mint 32 bit.
I now want to install Skype.
All the versions I find are for 64 bit. As I understand the last one working in 32 bit was Skype 4.3, that has been discontinued.
I have tried installing the current Deb package Skype offers with the terminal and the gdebi but it doesn't work.
I also searched for Skype with the Software Manager, but found only some Skype plug ins.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Linux Mint may be too heavy for such an old computer. You can use other distros tailored for older computers. Some examples of such distros are [LXLE](https://lxle.net/), [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux.com/), [anTiX](https://antixlinux.com/) or [Bodhi](https://www.bodhilinux.com). Alternatively, you can install a much older version of Ubuntu (e.g. 8.04 or 10.04), but then, don't connect it to internet, and use it as a home media center instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option to use Skype on a 32-bit machine (regardless of the operating system), is to use [Skype for Web](https://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-web/). The older versions are no longer compatible with the current protocols and Microsoft has deprecated all the old ones.

Note: Linux Mint is not supported here, but [you can certainly ask the people at the Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/) any questions you may have.

Comment: I tried but the sound is breaking, when I test call.